# Nav tab in bootstrap 4 not working if I provide routerlink in a tag

Tags: html, angular, css, bootstrap-4

I am working on bootstrap4 tabs and It is working fine if I don't provide routerlink in anchor tag,but if I provide link then only hover effect is working. please help me to resolve this problem.

Here is my code

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="header-nav">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#" routerLink="/account" id="account">Account</a>
            </li>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <li class="nav-item" >
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#" routerLink="/subscription" id="subscription-header">Subscription</a>
            </li>
        </div>
    </div>
</ul>
```

Thank you

Comment: You don't need href if you are using routerLink.

Comment: I removed that..same result

Comment: Can you post you module code as well

Answer (score 0):

Try placing this at the bottom of the document

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering..it is still same. It works if I remove routerLink

Comment: @Hussam The scripts you are providing are not for the same version of Bootstrap that the asker is using.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have imported router module in your module.

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


@NgModule({ imports: [ CommonModule, RouterModule ],
```

Comment: I imported that..Routerlink is working for me..tab effect is not working.

Comment: If I remove routerLink there is a box around tab if I click on any nav-item..but if I add routerLink,there will be no box if I click on tab ,but I can see box when I hover on it.

Comment: Well then that could be a css issue, in such cases i prefer to use NgPrime or Angular Material controls. which are made for Angular.